# Change button behaviour on (same) button click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really sorry if this was already asked, but my searching skills just didn't find something similar.

So I have a form with multiple subsections.
I need to hide/show subsections and 'simulate' the page as if it had 3 different parts.
There is no access to the source code, so everything has to be done through css/js applied over existing code.
Keep in mind that there is already a button (I'll call it *continueBtn* here) that submits the form when pressed and I added a back button. Assume that all the variables (allSections, sectionOne etc. exist, they are not the problem).

I created a function that shows/hides/changes text based on what step of the form we are in; example code:

```
function showHideOnStep(step){

            allSections.hide();
            continueBtn.unbind('click');
            backBtn.unbind('click');

            switch (step){
                case 1:
                    sectionOne.show();      

                    continueBtn.attr('type','button');//make continue button to not submit
                    continueBtn.text("Go to step 2");

                    backBtn.click(function(){
                        //go to previous browser page, literally
                    })
                    continueBtn.click(function(){
                        showHideOnStep(2);
                    })
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sectionTwo.show();
                    continueBtn.text("Go to step 3");
                    continueBtn.attr('type','button');//make continue button to not submit (in case it's a back from step 3)

                    continueBtn.click(function(){
                        showHideOnStep(1);
                    })
                    backBtn.click(function(){
                        showHideOnStep(3);
                    })
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sectionThree.show();

                    continueBtn.text("Submit");

                    backBtn.click(function(){
                        showHideOnStep(2);
                    })

                    continueBtn.removeAttr('type');//make continue button to submit again
                    break;
            }
        }
```

So let's say page loads and showHideOnStep(1) is applied by default. Everything's fine, clicking back will back, clicking Continue will go to Step 2. 
But now, when clicking Continue, it will jump to submitting, instead of going to case 3 first.

It's like the actual "clicking" ends after it removes the "type=button" from the button and it propagates into that.
Same issue will happen when Backing from Step 2. Instead of going to Step 1, it will back for good.

I'm sure there is either of

a) a fairly simple fix for this or
b) a much better/cleaner way to do what I want

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the button html script! If the button was made from a form submit tag, it will submit without going to the next. Trying using a button tag.

```js
//  for checking
var secondbutton = false;

// checks if its been clicked
var firstb = document.getElementById('first');

function second() {
  if(secondbutton == false) {
    alert("first");
    firstb.innerHTML = "Second";
    secondbutton = true;
  }
  else {
    alert("second")
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="first" onclick="second()">First</button>
```

This creates the illusion that it changed!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's a button (<button>). I read that adding the type=button on a button will prevent it from submitting. And it does. Problem is that when I click on it, instead of removing the 'type' attribute, so it submits on the next click, it removes + triggers the submit in the same click.

I'll try in the morning with a control var, to see what happens.